# Rails number_field ignoring requirements in haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, input, haml

I have the following code in my view

```
.fields
   = f.label :minimum_mpg
   %br
   = f.number_field :mpg_min, :in => 0..100, :type => 'float' , :precision => 2
```

I want to restrict the input from 0 to 100, but when I enter in negative numbers they are accepted. I think it has something to do with changing the type to float. The input needs to be able to accept floats though.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `:type => 'float'` line is overriding the default `type="number"` part of the HTML tag that is generated, effectively turning it back into a standard text field instead of a number field.

If you need to accept two decimal places, you could do something like this. However, clicking the up/down arrows on the field will only increment 0.01 at a time.

```
= f.number_field :mpg_min, :in => 0..100, :step => 0.01
```